# SL 4 Version Hell? The silverlight developer runtime is not installed please install a matching version

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I've been developing for and running Silverlight 4 for about a week.  A week ago I installed the Silverlight 4 design time components to develop and debug silverlight for VS 2010 - I posted some of these apps and they were used by users running SL4.  Today, I went to a website that told me to upgrade my SL (I think it was the MS expression site) - so I did that and all the sudden I get this error when running SL 4 apps within VS 2010.

The silverlight developer runtime is not installed please install a matching version

Installing the latest version of the Silverlight SDK does not correct this.  Basically I am stuck and unable to run Silverlight apps from VS2010.

Are versioning problems like this a common theme in SilverLight?  The only thing I can think of is that there is a minor version difference between the versions used on the the MS Expression web site and the version (SL4) I installed from MS site a few days ago?  However re-installing the latest version of SL4 does not correct this.

Any help?

Answer (score 6):

The developer runtime is a different download than the normal "end user" runtime.

Again quoting from [Tim Heur's Blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2011/02/14/silverlight-february-2011-update-gdr3.aspx), you need to look for the link under "getting the updates" that points to the developer runtime. This will allow you to debug etc.

Comment: This was more useful than the error message and download link VS was spitting back at me.